Next.js Cognito Refresh Access Token
I am using Credentials Provider connected to Cognito User Pool.
I can't update my access token when it expires.
I receive error : User is not authenticated.
I am using Next 14 and Next Auth 5.0.0-beta.19
I would like the access token to be renewed because I cannot force the user to log in every hour.
The access token is important because I use it as authentication for API requests.
This is my code :
export const { handlers, signIn, signOut, auth, update } = NextAuth({providers: [Credentials({credentials: {email: {},password: {},},
      authorize: async (credentials): Promise<any> => {
        Amplify.configure(amplifyConfig)
        try {
          const user: CognitoUser = await Auth.signIn(credentials.email as string, credentials.password as string)
          if (!user) {
            throw new Error("User not found.")
          }
          const session: CognitoUserSession | null = user.getSignInUserSession()
          if (session) {
            const accessToken = session.getAccessToken().getJwtToken()
            const refreshToken = session.getRefreshToken().getToken()
            const expiresAt = session.getAccessToken().getExpiration()
            return { email: user.getUsername(), accessToken: accessToken, refreshToken : refreshToken, expiresAt : expiresAt }
          } else {
            throw new Error("No session found")
          }
        } catch (e) {
          throw new Error("error")} }, }), ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }: { token: any, user: any }) {
      if (user) {
        token.accessToken = user?.accessToken
        token.refreshToken = user?.refreshToken
        token.expiresAt = user?.expiresAt
      }
      if(token.expiresAt < Date.now() / 1000) {
        try{
          if(token.refreshToken){
            await refreshToken(token)
          }
        }catch(e){
          console.log("Error refreshing token", e)
        }
      }
      return token
    },
    async session({ session, token }: { session: any; token: any }) {
      if (token) {
        session.accessToken = token?.accessToken
        session.refreshToken = token?.refreshToken
        session.expiresAt = token?.expiresAt
      }
      if(token.expiresAt < Date.now() / 1000) {
        console.log("Token expired")
        if(token.refreshToken){
          await refreshToken(token)
        }
      }
      return token
    }
  },
})
export const refreshToken = async (token: any) => {
  if(token){
    console.log("Token expired, refreshing")
    Amplify.configure(amplifyConfig) 
    const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
    console.log("User found", user)
    const session = await Auth.currentSession()
    user.refreshSession(session.getRefreshToken(), (err, session) => {
      console.log("Session refreshed", session)
      if(err){
        console.log("Error refreshing session", err)
        throw new Error("Error refreshing session")
      }
    })
    console.log("Session found", session)
    return { email: user.getUsername(), accessToken: session.getAccessToken().getJwtToken(), refreshToken : session.getRefreshToken().getToken() }

  }
}

I also tried to do that :
export const refreshToken = async (token: any) => {
  const host = "https://edillo.auth." + process.env.COGNITO_USER_POOL_REGION + ".amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token";
  console.log("Host", host)
  const base64 = Buffer.from(process.env.COGNITO_USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID + ":" + process.env.COGNITO_USER_POOL_CLIENT_SECRET).toString("base64")
  console.log("Base64", base64)
  console.log("Token in call", token)
  const response = await fetch(host, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "Authorization": "Basic " + base64,
    },
    body : {
      "grant_type": "refresh_token",
      "refresh_token": token.refreshToken,
      "client_id": process.env.COGNITO_USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID || "",
    }

  })
  
  const data = await response.json()
  console.log("Response refresh token", data)
}

but i receive { error: 'invalid_grant' }

Have you found a soultion?
